# Angular Animation not aligned

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am really new to Angular (<2 days) and have used the sample on https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating to create my first spa.  My goal is to add animations to the page transitions which I have done by adding ngAnimate:

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
```

You can see the full code on plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/eJ1JExySPrfRobjy1Bhq?p=preview

The animations are simply a slide out for the page leaving and a slide in for the new page. The problem, which you can see in plunker is that the sliding in page is not aligned with the one leaving - it slides in below the current page and when the transition is complete it jumps up into the final position. What I want is the sliding in page to replace the sliding out page.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Aidan

Comment: I can't see any animation in the plnkr link you provided..

Comment: I'm kind of new to this but I think the sample I have only works on firefox - the other browser support is missing from the css file.